# Magento 2: Can we delete 'setup' directory after successful magento 2 installation?

Tags: magento2, installation

Can we delete 'setup' directory after successful magento 2 installation ?

What are the directories/files we can delete after magento 2 successful installation, especially E:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.1\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Test directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you should not remove the setup directory, without it `bin/magento` will not work.

As far as what you can safely remove... not a lot. The installer cleans up any unnecessary files once the Magento installation is complete. 
The only files i can think of are the ones ending in `.sample` (they are used when you want to create a new version of the file) which you can easily find on the internet if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can we delete 'Test' directory inside E:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.1\setup\src\Magento\Setup

Comment: setup\src\Magento\Setup\Test is used for unit testing custom extensions.
It contains code used by the magento CLI ( bin/Magento ). 
Here is a link on how it's used. I would not recommend removing it if you plan to expand your store.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-test.html

Comment: You meant, if we don't plan to expand the store, then we can delete and it'll not affect, right?

Comment: Correct, so if you plan to never update/install an extension/theme than it shouldn't cause a problem.
Either way, i would not worry about "extra" files, the installer does a pretty good job of removing all unnecessary files.

Answer (score 3):

I dont have enough reputation to add a comment.

Regarding Radosav Answer, Please do not delete .sample files . Deleting those files will results in error when having cron jobs set.

This happened to me when I deleted the .htaccess.sample file from the root directory of  magento 2 website. I got the following error:

```
update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:  .htaccess.sample.
```

[Here is a list of files that should not be deleted](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/160449/48805)