# If i rename "setup" folder in root directory

Tags: magento2

There is folder named "Setup" in magento 2, what if i changed the folder name? is it affect anything on front-end?

Comment: why you want to change any specific reason?

Comment: When i access the {{Base_url}}/setup it says
    

Magento
Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters.
To use the Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard

Comment: Please refere this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131987/magento-2-can-we-delete-setup-directory-after-successful-magento-2-installati 
In short, you should not remove the setup directory, without it bin/magento will not work.

Comment: this happens when you already installed magento... one you install magento `[magento_dir]/setup` will not work anymore..

Comment: so how can i prevent the access {{Base URL}}/setup from browser @Msquare

Comment: @AnkurSharma use .htaccess file to redirect